# How can I get the current web directory from the URL?

Tags: php, preg-match

If I have a URL that is http://www.example.com/sites/dir/index.html, I would want to extract the word "sites". I know I have to use regular expressions but for some reason my knowledge of them is not working on PHP.

I am trying to use :

```
 $URL = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 preg_match("%^/(.*)/%", $URL, $matches);
```

But I must be doing something wrong. I would also like it to have a catch function where if it is at the main site, www.example.com then it would do the word "MAIN"

Edit: sorry, I've known about dirname...It gives the full directory path. I only want the first directory....   So if its www.example.com/1/2/3/4/5/index.html   then it returns just 1, not /1/2/3/4/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `dirname` function like this:

```
$dir =  dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$dirs = explode('/', $dir);
echo $dirs[0]; // get first dir
```

Comment: Please note that while the answer asks to get the path from the URL, the reply is giving the path from the filesystem, so while the two in this case are the same, this is actually plain wrong. If your url, `http://www.example.com/sites/dir/index.html`, is handled by a script in another folder (ModRewrite), say `/www/home/scripts/wholesite.php`, this answer would return "home" instead of "sites". PHP_SELF "is the script", while REQUEST_URI "is the url".

Answer (score 1):

The dirname function should get you what you need

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

```
<?php
    $URL = dirname($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
?>
```

Comment: Doesn't work if the request is for a directory and is served by the default file (normally index.php)

Comment: doesn't work if there isn't a slash at the end of the URL

Answer (score 1):

Use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) to get the path from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and then you could get the path segments with [`explode`](http://php.net/explode):

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$segments = explode('/', substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'], 1));

echo $segments[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to recommend additionally to check for a prefixed "/" or "\" 
and to use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR :

```
$testPath = dirname(__FILE__);
$_testPath = (substr($testPath,0,1)==DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) ? substr($testPath,1):$testPath;
$firstDirectory = reset( explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, dirname($_testPath)) );
echo $firstDirectory;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and robust way is:

```
$currentWebDir = substr(__DIR__, strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']));
```

If you are worried about DIRECTORY_SEPARATORS, you could also do:

```
$currentWebDir = str_replace('\\', '/', substr(__DIR__, strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])));
```

Also be aware of mod_rewrite issues mentioned by FrancescoMM